# How to get position of an element in array that matches a certain regexp?

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays

I was wondering how I can get the index of an element from an array, that matches a given regexp.

For example:

```
["This is 23", "1234 lorem ipsum", "Some more text"]
```

Now, how do I get the index of the string that matches `/\d{4}/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p array.index{|x| x =~ /\d{4}/ } #=> 1
```

And if you are planning to get the items out of the array:

```
p array.grep(/\d{4}/) #=> ["1234 lorem ipsum"]
```